# Working with a more complicated xml document

Tags: ios, xml, arrays

Hi guys im using gdataxml library, and was working with a sample file : http://daniarnaout.com/School.xml

```
NSData *xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://daniarnaout.com/School.xml"]];
GDataXMLDocument *doc =[[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:xmlData options:0 error:nil];

NSArray *names =[doc nodesForXPath:@"//School/Student/Name" error:nil];
for(GDataXMLElement *name in names) { NSLog(@"name: %@ \n",name.stringValue); }
```

This works well, except that now i want to go onto working with the real document ftp://ftp2.bom.gov.au/anon/gen/fwo/IDV10753.xml

i can print the xml to the log with `NSLog(@"%@",doc.rootElement);`

but if i change the xpath to `//product/forecast/,` i'm not getting anything.

basically i want to grab the details for `<area aac="VIC_PT025"`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `nil` (error) here?

```
NSArray *names =[doc nodesForXPath:@"//School/Student/Name" error:nil];
```

You are not catching the error. For the second XML, you could have known that there is something wrong with your xpath. Instead of `//product/forecast/`, remove the extra `/` at the end of the expression; you need `//product/forecast`.